# How to develop child theme for thesis

Tags: theme-development, theme-thesis

I have `thesis theme` but for that thesis I want to create a child theme but I am not find out any help for starting.
even i have search on Internet but nothing found
Hey any body have any idea regard this then please help me.
I am waiting for your reply

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you know this but you can edit your comments after you save them so you don't need to leave 2 or 3 comments if you forgot to say something, one right after the other. Instead just edit your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The Thesis framework uses a unique system to customize while inheriting the parent theme's functions and styles, different from the typical Wordpress method of child/parent themes. You don't actually build a separate theme folder with Thesis - you edit the files within `/wp-content/themes/thesis/custom/` (or if it doesn't exist yet, change the name of the "custom-sample" folder to "custom" and then edit the contents).

There are two basic files to start with - `custom_functions.php` and `custom.css`. Place any code you would normally place in the `functions.php` file of a child theme into `custom_functions.php`, and place any CSS you would normally place in the `style.css` of a child theme into `custom.css`.

Thesis reads these two files and automatically injects them like a child theme when rendering. There's an images folder inside of `/custom` you can use for your graphics, too.

The great thing about this system of customizing Thesis is that it's completely self-contained - you can copy your `/custom` folder to any other site running thesis, and your customizations also won't be overwritten by updates to the Thesis theme itself.

Comment: hey actually with custom-function.php i can change everything.But i want to develop child theme for thesis theme if you have any suggestion regard this then please let me know

Comment: if you know can you send me the step for develop child theme and also how it works on frontend

Comment: thanks for reply but if you find out anything then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Shalu, I have not created any child themes, but as ***somatic*** said, the best and easiest way with Thesis is to make your edits to the **custom.css** and **custom_functions.php** files.  These files become portable and can be used in any Thesis design.

If you really want to create a Thesis child theme, here's an article from Kristarella that I bookmarked which guides you through the the steps. http://www.kristarella.com/2010/10/wordpress-child-themes-and-thesis/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Thesis/DIY Themes offers tutorials for that. Have you bought or just downloaded the theme "somewhere"?